# ant not working on my ubuntu, command: ant -version

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse, ant

Following command `ant -version` is throwing error `Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar`

screen shot:

```
du@ubuntu-pc:~/workspace/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects$ ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```

I do have my JAVA_HOME configured. And `java -version` does run without any issue

Comment: Try `echo $JAVA_HOME`. Are you getting the specified path?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run ant successfully by installing the default JDK as follows:

```
apt-get install default-jdk
```